# Can't change the language of SSMS to English

Tags: settings, ssms-2014

The option "Use the language of Microsoft Windows" in "International Settings" is chosen:

[image: Screenshot of my International Settings]

---

And the Windows language is **English**, as seen here:

[image]

---

**Other solutions**

- I have also tried completely deleting the German Version and Reinstalling the English one.
- My VS2017 is in English

---

Looking forward to any suggestions, thank you !

Comment: Did you perhaps find a solution for this problem?

Comment: @splattne, thank you for your interest, but unfortunately the problem still persists.

Comment: I thought about installing the newest version of SMSS (preview).

Comment: @splattne it actually did half of the trick. At least the Object Explorer is in English now. Still, the menu and all the settings are in German. Does if have something to do with registry ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! If I find something new about the problem I'll let you know.

Comment: @splattne Thank you for you time and effort ! I'll be looking out for your messages.